# RestController autowire interface nosuchbeandefinition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I wrote an application using spring-boot 1.5.10 RELEASE. I need to autowire interface which I will be use as WebService.
I have got configuration class:

```
package com.app.packA;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StartWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StartWebApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(StartWebApplication.class);
}
```

}

My RestController:

```
package com.app.packA;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

@Autowired
CalculatorWs calcService;

}
```

and interface from another package

```
package com.app.packB;

@WebService(name="CalculatorService")
public interface CalculatorWs {

public int sum();

public int multiply();
}
```

When I try to start this application on Tomcat 7, I received message that In "GreetingController" NoSuchBeanDefinition "CalculatorWs"

Comment: I can't see any implementation of `CalculatorWs` with `@Component`.

Comment: two thing you need implementation of `CalculatorWs` and also it needs to be under `com.app.packA` package

Comment: i cannot move it in another package

Comment: Spring will not automatically detect this class as it is in a different package. Either move your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to `com.app` instead of where it is now. Second it is a JAX-WS webservice, which will, without additional libraries not be detected or instantiated. YOu will need an `@Bean` to bootstrap that JAX-WS webservice proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `@Service` instead of `@WebService`

Comment: thanks, i did it in another way. I create new class with annotation @Service and add my interface as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the package com.app.packB to your spring boot app.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.app")
```

Or maybe you want to add specific packages to scan.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.app.packA", "com.app.packB"})
```

Comment: I try to do so, but then I had got 404 page from browser

Comment: Do you check the logs? Enable the  logger.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @earandap worked like magic for me

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.app")
Or maybe you want to add specific packages to scan.

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.app.packA", "com.app.packB"})
```